# Ask for server receipt for xmpp message in Swift

Tags: swift, xmppframework

I want to know if the message has received at server. I know how to get delivery receipt which means the message is delivered to the user.

```
    xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts = XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts(dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
```

but I want to know if my message has received to the server.

Answer (score 3):

there is no way of recognizing that because of deprecated extension for events.you can just understand that message successfully send from your client or not using these functions:

`func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didSend message: XMPPMessage) {
        print(message.body)
    }`

`func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didFailToSend message: XMPPMessage, error: Error) {
        print(message.body)
    }`

Comment: Sorry, one question. Do you have a reference that tells we don't have this option? and the extension is deprecated?